# Does drush sql-sync support inter-db syncing?

Tags: database, drush

Can I use `drush sql-sync` between MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot switch database types using `drush sql-sync`.  However, the [DBTNG Database Migrator](http://drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator) tool will do the conversion for you.